# Java, could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I am a new learner for Java and recently I have installed JAVA SE JDK and set up system environment as follows:

**ClassPath**

```
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\dt.jar
```

**JAVA_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

**JRE_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144 (I added this because fail to run java program)
```

**JRE_HOME_141**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141 (I added this because fail to run java program)
```

**Path**

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME_141%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%PATH%
```

I could compile my code using javac FirstProgram.java without problem but once i tried to run java FirstProgram.class, it shows this error message:

> Error: could not find or load main class FirstProgram.java

I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the java installation, you can remove duplicate path variables. Please post `FirstProgram.java`. Also, do not rewrite by hand the error message you get, copy-paste it. The output you wrote is unlikely to be given by the `java` executable.

Comment: Please add your FirstProgram.java-Sourcecode

Answer (score 1):

> but once i tried to run `java FirstProgram.class`, it shows this error message:- `Error: could not find or load main class FirstProgram.java`

You need to specify the full class name of the main class. Maybe `FirstProgram`. Maybe `mypackage.FirstProgram`.  But not `FirstProgram.class` (that is the name the file the class is stored in, it will need to be present on the classpath) or `FirstProgram.java` (that is the name of the Java source code file, it is not needed at runtime).